# How do I test the difference between two dependent correlation coefficients whilst controlling for other variables?

Tags: regression, correlation, generalized-linear-model, independence, partial-correlation

How do I test the difference between r(X,Y) and r(X,Z) [Williams Test?] whilst controlling for  demographic variables that were measured in addition to X and Y and Z [Partial Correlation]?

Thanks, Moimeme

Comment: What kind of data is it, continuous, discrete, mixed? Is the multi-variate Normal distribution a decent approximation? Basically what you are after is testing *conditional independence*.

Comment: Thank you! It is continous data, x is a questionnaire measurements of emotion and y and z are measurements of different concepts of intelligence (so it is all test scores).

Comment: could i compare two partial correlation coefficients using the Steiger or Williams or Hotelling Test?

Comment: i see that it was done here: http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0076825#pone.0076825-Steiger1

Comment: One way would be to calculate the 3x3 covariance matrix and then invert it. That is sometimes called the precision matrix or Fisher matrix. If the off diagonal Y-Z term is zero or close to zero then Y and Z are independent and just conditionally dependent through X. I don't know off-hand whether this assumes normally distributed data. Would have to look into it more.

Comment: There are some R packages for dealing with these kind of things such as gaussian graphical models. gRain gRim, glasso etc. Have a look at those. Sometimes it works better to apply a transformation to make it more Gaussian. The Huge package has tools to do that.

Comment: but the williams t2 statistics as proposed in steiger (1980) cannot be used to compare the correlation coefficients?